# What method should I use to store many categories of data?

Tags: database-design

The issue I'm having, is that my app is trying to show a client several months of their invoicing history, and I am unsure of how to save all of the data.

Currently I have all of my Many Clients Data stored in a SQLiteDatabase, and I assume this would be the easiest option, though I have no idea how to go about saving their prior purchases.

Should I continue to use SQLite and just build more columns for each prior charge, or is there a better option?

DB Schema is

TABLE=CUSTOMERS

```
COLUMN1=ID
COLUMN2=NAME
COLUMN3=ADDRESS
COLUMN4=SPECIAL NOTES
```

From here the best way I can think of, is adding columns for the Services that were charged, and three copys of them so as to have months prior history. Such as,

```
Col4month1=Service1
Col5month1=Service2
Col6month1=Service3
Col7month1=Service4

Col8month2=Service1
Col9month2=Service2
Col10month2=Service3
Col11month2=Service4
```

Surely there is an easier way to do this

Comment: I'd guess you need more rows, with a timestamp each, which would imply another table. But it's hard to say without seeing the DB schema and example data.

Comment: How exactly would you ask this question? Anyhow for anyone that has anything more helpful than the popup that came up while creating this post, I will Post my DB Scheme as well As I can.

Comment: Definitely share your schema, or a representative sample of that schema.  Shooting from the hip, though, this sounds like a job for an Invoice table, as @CL

Comment: Thanks I am thinking a Second table may be best for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post your schema, or a representative sample of it, I can tailor this a bit, but based on your description it sounds like you need a child table, as CL suggested.  It would look something like this:

```
Client
    ID              --primary key
    First_Name
    Last_Name
    etc.

Invoice
    ID              --primary key
    Client_ID       --foreign key link to Client
    Invoice_Date
    Invoice_Amount
    etc.

Invoice_Line_Item
    ID              --primary key
    Invoice_ID      --foreign key link to Invoice
    Item_Number
    Quantity
    etc.
```

With the above structure, a client can have multiple invoices, each invoice can have multiple items, and they all link together on the foreign keys.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks very much, perfect Answer. Will update on how this goes. I have upvoted your awnser but I am too new :( Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're very welcome - we were all new to this at one point.  Be sure to mark this as "accepted" - I'm given to understand that that makes it easier for others to find.